# flip a div and change the color of the inside divs when flipped?

Tags: html, css, dom

There is a wrap div inside of which there are various divs, some of which are position absolute.

When i hover over the Wrap div it is flipped using the transformY: rotate(180deg) property and now the back side of the div is visible. I want to change the color of all the inside elements to let say black, when the wrap div is flipped.

Here is the code snippet of my problem. I want to change the color of the divs(currently red) to something else when their back side is visible but as soon as they are in original position they again regain the color red.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.wrap:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}

.div1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "9";
  top: 2px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  background: red;
}

.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with a solution, hope this is what you want

```css
body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

.wrap:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.wrap:hover .div1, .wrap:hover .div2, .wrap:hover .div1:after {
  background-color: #333;
}

.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease .3s;
          transition: background .2s ease .3s;
}

.div1:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  top: 2px;
  left: 120px;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: red;
  background: red;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: background .2s ease .3s;
}

.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: background .2s ease .3s;
          transition: background .2s ease .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Elegant solution. But as soon a hover over the wrap div the color of the inside elements get changed. I want them to be changed only when the wrap has fully flipped. Any idea how can i do that?

Comment: @vikrantnegi007: You need to add a delay to the `background` property's transition.

Comment: @Harry Ok Great. 
One more question. Now i'm not using hover to flip the wrap, instead i'm using the animation css3 property to flip it infinitely. 
How can i change the background color now?

Comment: @vikrantnegi007: It will be similar, you'll have to tweak the keyframes accordingly. The approach needs to be detailed, comments is too small for it and adding an answer to this thread won't be apt because this is about transition. I think you should accept GOB's answer and ask a different question for that.

Comment: @harry agreed! btw. I've made the changes with the transition-delay in my answer